# Integrating Fastlane with CircleCI: Cocoapods framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, circleci, fastlane

I am trying to setup CircleCI for my iOS app and I want to integrate with Fastlane.
My circle.yml looks like this:

```
machine:
 xcode:
    version: 8.3.1

dependencies:
  pre:
    - gem install bundler

  post:
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec pod install
    - bundle exec fastlane test
```

The building it's fine until it finish compiling the test files; It shows this error

```
[04:39:38]: ▸ Compiling LoginViewControllerSpec.swift
[04:39:38]: ▸ Compiling QuestionSpec.swift
[04:39:38]: ▸ Compiling ItemSpec.swift
[04:39:38]: ▸ Linking myApp-iosTests
[04:39:38]: ▸ ❌  ld: framework not found Pods_Tests_myAppTests
[04:39:38]: ▸ ❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And here is the Podfile (I use cocoapods v1.2.1)

```
target 'myApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

    pod "PulsingHalo"
    pod 'OpenTok'
    pod 'Alamofire', '4.0'
    pod 'PieCharts'
    pod 'SwiftHEXColors'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
    pod 'OAuthSwiftAlamofire'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'


  target 'myAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'Quick'
        pod 'Nimble'
  end

  target 'myAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'Quick'
    pod 'Nimble'
  end

end
```

I have tried for two days without any success. I also changed the Build options in the Tests Target
[image]

I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

Thank you

Comment: This line doesn't make sense `Pods_Tests_myAppTests`, it supposed to be `Pods_myAppTests ` , could you open your workspace and go to each target's `build phases-> link binary with libraries` to check what are the `.framework` names

Comment: @u.gen There's 2 frameworks there: 
Pods_Tests_myAppTests.framework
Pods_myApp_Tests.framework

Both set as required

Comment: I deleted that frameworks because as you said, didn't make any sense. I don't know when they were created but now it's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome, please accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make sure your target names in podfile matches with binary frameworks name in your buildphases.

Also a side note; Nothing wrong with `bundle exec pod install` but I would move `pod install` to fastlane, there is a lane called `before_all` that can install the pods for you before your test lane.

```
platform :ios do |options|
  before_all do |lane, options|
   cocoapods // this would replace pod install
  end
```